# Updating records in a mysql table that were overwritten using records in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I had to update the id's of certain records in mysql. Few of the sql queries were:

```
update table set col_id =17 where col_id =1 and id_ori like 'set-%'; 
update table set col_id =18 where col_id =2 and id_ori like 'set-%'; 
update table set col_id =19 where col_id =4 and id_ori like 'set-%';
update table set col_id =30 where col_id =17 and id_ori like 'set-%';
update table set col_id =31 where col_id =18 and id_ori like 'set-%';
update table set col_id =32 where col_id =19 and id_ori like 'set-%';
```

For example:
You can see that the records having col_id "1" are set with cold_id "17" and so on. Then records having col_id "17" are set with col_id "30". This is where the issue occurred. All the records having col_id "17" were overwritten with col_id "30".

But I have the table backup with me. I am not sure how to use the backup table to rectify the records in the original table. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The same would have happened had i updated col_id 17 to 30 first because there are other records with col_id 30 which had to be updated with some other id

Comment: Can you just restore from backup?

Comment: We have additional records in the table now. Would those records get affected when I go for the backup?

Comment: It depends how you restore.  If there's a cutoff point between new and old records (e.g. col_ids > 100 are new records since the backup) you could delete all records with an id <= 100 and re-insert from the backup file.